# Uncaught ReferenceError: calculator is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ,

Tags: javascript, html

Developer tools/troubleshooting tells me that calculator is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick. Everything works except that I don`t get an answer. Do anyone see what I am doing wrong? I follow an example, an the example works. But not my code. I get four buttons, and two textfields, but not an answer when I click on the buttons, with number in the textfields.

Have posted this before, but not with the entire code the first time. Only when I edited it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
         <head>
           <title>oppg.3</title>
         </head>
       <body>

         <input id="v1" type="text" style="width:5em;"/>
         <button onclick="calculator.sum();"> + </button>
         <button onclick="calculator.multiply();"> * </button>
         <button onclick="calculator.div();"> / </button>
         <button onclick="calculator.mod();"> % </button>
         <input id="v2" type="text" style="width:5em;"/>
         <span id="result"> </span>


       <script type="text/javascript">
    var Calculator = function(inp1,inp2,reslt) {
        this.valinp1 = inp1;
        this.valinp2 = inp2;
        this.result = reslt;
        if (!Calculator.prototype.sum) {
          Calculator.prototype.sum = function() {
            var value1 = Number(this.valinp1.value),
                value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);

                this.result.innerHTML =
                 (!/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)))
                 : (value1 + value2);
            };
            Calculator.prototype.multiply = function() {
              var value1 = Number(this.valinp1.value);
              var value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);
              this.result.innerHTML =
                (!/[0-9]/.test(string(value1)) || !/[0-9]/.test(string(value1)))
                :(value1*value2);

            };
            Calculator.prototype.div = function() {
               var value = Number(this.valinp1.value);
               var value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);
               var restmp = value1/value2;
               this.result.innerHTML =
                 (!/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || value2 === 0)
                 : restmp%1 ? restmp.toFixed(3) : restmp;
            };
            Calculator.prototype.mod = function() {
              var value1 = Number(this.valinp1.value);
              var value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);
              var restmp = value1%value2;
              this.result.innerHTML =
              (!/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || value2 === 0)
              : value1%value2;

            };
          }
      };
      calculator =
         new Calculator (
             document.getElementById('v1'),
             document.getElementById('v2'),
             document.getElementById('result')
        );
        </script>


      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the Developer Tools in your browser. Look at the Console. Read the error messages. **Fix the first problem first**. Subsequence problems are often consequences of earlier problems.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Or run the code through [JS Hint](http://jshint.com/) which can give more useful error messages:

> Expected '}' to match '{' from line 6 and instead saw ':'.

It looks like you are trying to write a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) but forgot the `?` character and the alternative state.

You've made this mistake several times.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <title>oppg.3</title>
     </head>
   <body>

     <input id="v1" type="text" style="width:5em;"/>
     <button onclick="calculator.sum();"> + </button>
     <button onclick="calculator.multiply();"> * </button>
     <button onclick="calculator.div();"> / </button>
     <button onclick="calculator.mod();"> % </button>
     <input id="v2" type="text" style="width:5em;"/>
     <span id="result"> </span>


   <script type="text/javascript">
var Calculator = function(inp1,inp2,reslt) {
    this.valinp1 = inp1;
    this.valinp2 = inp2;
    this.result = reslt;
    if (!Calculator.prototype.sum) {
      Calculator.prototype.sum = function() {
        var value1 = Number(this.valinp1.value),
            value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);

            this.result.innerHTML =
             !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) ? !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1))
             : (value1 + value2);
        };
        Calculator.prototype.multiply = function() {
          var value1 = Number(this.valinp1.value);
          var value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);
          this.result.innerHTML =
            !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) ? !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1))
            :(value1*value2);

        };
        Calculator.prototype.div = function() {
           var value = Number(this.valinp1.value);
           var value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);
           var restmp = value1/value2;
           this.result.innerHTML =
             !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) ? !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || value2 === 0
             : restmp%1 ? restmp.toFixed(3) : restmp;
        };
        Calculator.prototype.mod = function() {
          var value1 = Number(this.valinp1.value);
          var value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);
          var restmp = value1%value2;
          this.result.innerHTML =
          !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) ? !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || value2 === 0
          : value1%value2;

        };
      }
  };
  calculator =
     new Calculator (
         document.getElementById('v1'),
         document.getElementById('v2'),
         document.getElementById('result')
    );
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

You made a number of errors, using `||` instead of ternary and using `string` instead of `String` in the multiply function. The above code should work now